# JQuery 4 button menu, on click hide divs and show others, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four buttons on my website. When you click one button, the button itself should become invisible, and a new text should become visible. The other text should be invisible when you click that link, and the other menu buttons should be visible.

To make clear what I mean, I have made a list. In this list you can see what SHOULD happen when you click certain buttons, and what should happen when you open the website:

---

When you OPEN the website, this should be the case:
**".menu-home-link, .menu-government-text, .menu-voice-text, .menu-news-text"** should be hidden, and **".menu-home-text, .link-your-voice, link-nation-news, .link-government"** should be visible.

---

What I want to happen when you click a menu button:

If you click **"Menu-home-link"** -> **".menu-home-link, .menu-government-text, .menu-voice-text, .menu-news-text"** should become hidden, and **".menu-home-text, .link-your-voice, link-nation-news, .link-government"** should become visible.

If you click **".link-your-voice"** -> **".link-your-voice, .menu-government-text, .menu-home-text, .menu-news-text"** should become hidden, and **".menu-voice-text, menu-home-link, link-nation-news, .link-government"** should become visible.

If you click **".link-nation-news"** -> **".link-nation-news, .menu-government-text, .menu-home-text, .menu-voice-text"** should become hidden, and **".menu-news-text, Menu-home-link, link-your-voice, .link-government"** should become visible.

If you click **".link-government"** -> **".link-government, .menu-news-text, .menu-home-text, .menu-voice-text"** should become hidden, and **".menu-government-text, Menu-home-link, link-your-voice, .link-nation-news"** should become visible.

---

Currently I have the following jQuery code, I tried to duplicate it for all possible scenarios, but then it isn't working. Can someone help me to make the above clicks all work?

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $(".menu-home-link, .menu-government-text, .menu-voice-text, .menu-news-text").hide();

    $(".link-government, .link-home, link-your-voice, link-nation-news").bind("click", function () {

      $(".menu-home-link, .menu-home-text").hide();        

      if ($(this).attr("class") == "link-government")
      {
        $(".menu-home-link, .link-your-voice, .link-nation-news").show();
          $(".menu-government-text").show();
          $(".link-government").hide();
      }
      else 
      { 
        $(".menu-home-text").show();
          $(".link-government").show();
          $(".menu-government-text").hide();
      }       
    });

});
<script>
```

It has to work with the following HTML:

```
        <div class="menu-home">
            <!-- The first link -->
            <div class="menu-home-link"><a href="#" class="link-home"><span data-hover="Home" >Home</span></a></div>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- The first content -->
            <div class="menu-home-text"><div class="menu-homeline"></div><div class="menu-topline"></div><div class="menu-home-slogan">TODAY,<br>TOMORROW,<br>FOREVER.</div>
            <div class="menu-bottomline"></div></div>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
        <div class="menu-government">
            <!-- The second link -->
            <a href="#" class="link-government"><span data-hover="The Government">The Government</span></a>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- The second content -->
            <div class="menu-government-text"><div class="menu-governmentline"></div><div class="menu-topline"></div><div class="menu-home-slogan">THE<br>GOVERNMENT</div>
            <div class="menu-bottomline"></div>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
        <div class="menu-your-voice">
            <!-- The third link  -->
            <a href="#" class="link-your-voice"><span data-hover="Your Voice">Your Voice</span></a>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- The third content -->
            <div class="menu-voice-text"><div class="menu-governmentline"></div><div class="menu-topline"></div><div class="menu-home-slogan">YOUR<br>VOICE</div>
            <div class="menu-bottomline"></div>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
        <div class="menu-news">
            <!-- The fourth link -->
            <a href="#" class="link-nation-news"><span data-hover="Nation News">Nation News</span></a>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- The fourth content -->
            <div class="menu-news-text"><div class="menu-governmentline"></div><div class="menu-topline"></div><div class="menu-home-slogan">NATION<br>NEWS</div>
            <div class="menu-bottomline"></div>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
```

Kind regards,
Milan

Comment: have you thought about showing some HTML or CSS?

Comment: fiddle speaks more than 1000 words

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir why fiddle? SO has all the necessary tools to not outsource code to external websites.

Comment: I didn't think any html or css was needed? I typed here all the classes (with a . in front of them). And in the css there is nothing useful other then how those div's look. All I want is for the classes I told here, to be hidden, or shown when clicking on the class, once again provided above.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```js
$("nav a").click(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("nav .active, #pages .active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).add( $(this.hash) ).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
nav li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  padding:10px;
}
nav a.active{
  display:none;
}
#pages > div{
  display:none;
}
#pages .active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#a" class="active">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">d</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="pages">
  <div id="a" class="active">A text</div>
  <div id="b">B text</div>
  <div id="c">C text</div>
  <div id="d">D text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to do what I want it to do. I tried to implant it in my current html, but I can't seem to get it to work. Check my mainpost, I added the html. Maybe you can see how I could implant it, in that html? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You could add extra classes to the exciting once, so that I can add new classed without having to edit the old ones. Hopefully you can help me. Kind regards, Milan